# applying law of large numbers to matrices?

Tags: probability

Let us consider a random matrix X such that 1) entries are independently drawn, 2) its diagonal terms come from mean $1$ distribution 3)non-diagonal terms from mean $0$ distribution.

$X_n$ is iid copy of $X$.

In this case, I am wondering for a given matrices $A,B$ whether it holds or not.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n A X_n B \to AB
\end{align}

I think it holds because everything is linear and entries are independently drawn, but want to confirm it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It has to hold. Observe that it's enough to show that $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \longrightarrow \text{Id}_n \quad~ \text{a.s.}$$

---

Remember that $X_i$'s are matrix-valued random variables, i.e. each of its elements are random variables too.

- Take a sequence of diagonal elements of the $(i,i)^\text{th}$ position, i.e. $\{X_{ii}^{(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ . By SLLN, $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {X_{ii}^{(k)}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[X_{ii}] = 1\quad \text{a.s.} $$
- Take a sequence of non-diagonal elements of the $(i,j)^\text{th}$ position, i.e. $\{X_{ij}^{(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ . By SLLN, $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {X_{ij}^{(k)}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[X_{ij}] = 0\quad \text{a.s.} $$

Since all the entries of all the matrices are drawn independently, thus we have $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \longrightarrow \text{Id}_n\quad~\text{a.s.}$$ which is what we were needed to prove.